# Check for specific input valid format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a field for danish social security number that have to be validated for the correct format which is 123456-1234.

I am not sure how to check for this value in Javascript.

I am adding a method to jQuery Validator

```
$.validator.addMethod("cprFormat", function(value, element) {
    var validFormat = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var cprNoValue = $("#cprNo").val();
    return validFormat.test(cprNoValue);
}, 'CPR-nummer er ikke gyldigt');
```

But I am missing the correct regex in validFormat var

Comment: Use `var validFormat = /^\d{6}-\d{4}$/;` if you mean to match a string that starts with 6 digits, then `-`, and then ends with 4 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you should use is

```
/[0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{4}$/
```

On the future please try and use the next website to create and test live different regex.

https://regex101.com/r/NROuia/1

Later edit: or better, the one wrote by  Wiktor Stribiżew

```
/^\d{6}-\d{4}$/
```